# Is it possible databinding of enums by name in grails?

Tags: grails

I have search an example of databinding of enum by name in grails but I don't found any. I want to pass the enum name in the request and bind the enum as action's argument. I need automatic binding i.e. binding without call explicitly of `Enum.valueOf(params.val)`.

Is it possible automatic databinding of enums by name in grails? if yes how can I achieve this? I'm using grails 2.5.1

Comment: The framework doesn't support binding request parameters directly to Enums as arguments to controller actions, but does support binding to enum properties in a command object.

Answer (score 2):

May be you can try BindUsing annotation, something like

```
@BindUsing({ quarter, source ->
Enum.valueOf(source['val'])
    })
Enum val
```

http://mrhaki.blogspot.in/2015/04/grails-goodness-custom-data-binding.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm using 2.4.5 so perhaps something has changed, but it's not possible directly because Enums can't be instantiated using reflection and that is what is happening behind the scenes.

In `ControllersApi`'s `initializeCommandObject` method there is a check to see if the binding class is a domain class - `isDomainClass`, and it fails.

The same method attempts `newInstance()` on the type:

```
} else if (requestMethod == HttpMethod.POST || !isDomainClass) {
    commandObjectInstance = type.newInstance();
}
```

Which throws an `InstantiationException`, that is caught and rethrown again.  It's interesting that before it rethrows the exception, it looks for matching exception handling methods in the controller.

```
def instantiationException(final InstantiationException exception) {
    render "I've been caught"
}
```

This will 'successfully' execute, but with little value in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a plain enum like the following:

```
enum SomeEnum {
    ONE, TWO, THREE
}
```

And a class with a corresponding property:

```
class SomeDomain {
    SomeEnum someEnum
}
```

The binder can bind a `String` to the `someEnum` property and do the conversion for you...

```
new SomeDomain(someEnum: 'ONE')
```

Comment: The original question says " I need automatic binding i.e. binding without call explicitly of Enum.valueOf(params.val)".  The data binder does that at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/bd7741b646e13da598926cf118fad0221590e567/grails-databinding/src/main/groovy/grails/databinding/SimpleDataBinder.groovy#L578.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

Databinding of controller actions only supports two categories: basic types (primitives) and command objects so enums are not supported by default.

[From Grails 2.5.1 docs:](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.1/guide/theWebLayer.html)

> Controller action arguments are subject to request parameter data binding. There are 2 categories of controller action arguments. The first category is command objects. Complex types are treated as command objects. See the Command Objects section of the user guide for details. The other category is basic object types. Supported types are the 8 primitives, their corresponding type wrappers and java.lang.String.

For support databinding of enums in grails (by name is the default) you have to use the enum *inside a command object*.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, It is possible. If I recall correctly, the trick is to have a constructor defined for the enum, that takes the code as the attribute and creates the corresponding enum.

Now specify the data type of action parameter as the enum.

Comment: Do you really need a constructor?  I am pretty sure you don't.  I think the binder knows how to deal with that.